# How to decode int256 from tx data?

Tags: hex, decode, smartcontracts, web3py

I am looking at a [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa9042e6cc23919bc5d87931e5ec808a3dbf11e9b5b32ecc1de6fba79f3f2baf7#eventlog)'s data:
`Swap (index_topic_1 address sender, index_topic_2 address recipient, int256 amount0, int256 amount1, uint160 sqrtPriceX96, uint128 liquidity, int24 tick)`
and the hex data is:
`0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffe653efdc88fa14d9d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c574ce6000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011ad1d847f2d99bd6b83ba95c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023b32292becc65a2200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007c8`

I am trying to decode the arguments.

Decoding a positive integer is easy:

```
# remove the 0x
data = data[2:]
# decode the 64 char
amount1 = int(data[64:128], base=16)
assert amount1 == 522799489731071574016`
```

But I am failing to create a function that will decode the negative `amount0` from `bytes_amount0 = int(data[0:64], base=16)`.
I need a function that can decode both positive and negative `int256` as I don't know in advance which is positive and which is negative.